# spark submit is failing when a job is submitted in cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to execute `Tweets` example in cluster mode. It is failing with the following error:

```
C:\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\bin>spark-submit  --master spark://10.156.11.126:7077  --deploy-mode cluster --class example.PrintTweets C:\Users\j1008523\workspace1\target\scala-2.11\spark-twitter-lang-classifier-assembly-2.0.0

Running Spark using the REST application submission protocol.
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
17/06/14 10:36:48 INFO RestSubmissionClient: Submitting a request to launch an application in spark://10.156.11.126:7077.
17/06/14 10:37:00 WARN RestSubmissionClient: Unable to connect to server spark://10.156.11.126:7077.
Warning: Master endpoint spark://10.156.11.126:7077 was not a REST server. Falling back to legacy submission gateway instead.
17/06/14 10:37:03 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

When I remove `--deploy-mode cluster` it works and displays tweets on console

I built the package using sbt assembly so all the dependent jars are present in 
`spark-twitter-lang-classifier-assembly-2.0.0`.  I am running on windows system

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: The above issue is resolved by following related items.  There is no problem with the way cluster mode is run.

Comment: After looking at the error log from spark master ui i could find the code issue and was able to resolve .